# Show additional data in the response from another table that is connected via a many-to-many relation by TypeORM in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have four tables `users`, `ingredients`, `recipes` and a connection table `ingredients_ingrec_recipes` that TypeORM created automatically. This connection table consists of two columns: `ingredientsId` and `recipesId`.

In the `ingredient.entity.ts` file I have defined `@ManyToMany` relation with `{ eager:true }` between `ingredients` and `recipes`. When I make a Get-Request for a specific ingredient (via Postman), I also see the associated recipes in the response automatically, thanks to the magic of { eager: true } and TypeORM+NestJS.

Now I need exactly the same, but for recipes  (other side). **In the recipe response, the corresponding ingredients should also be displayed.** Unfortunately, according to TypeORM, I can only use `@ManyToMany` with `{ eager: true }` in one of the two entities. In order to achieve the same with recipes, I have to do this somehow via `leftJoinAndSelect()`. However, I don't know how to do this via this connection table `ingredients_ingrec_recipes` in my code.

Here is my code:

ingredient.entitiy.ts

```
@Entity({ name: 'ingredients' })
export class IngredientEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  slug: string;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  description: string;

  // more fields

  @ManyToMany(() => RecipeEntity, { eager: true })
  @JoinTable()
  ingrec: RecipeEntity[];

  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.recipes, { eager: true })
  author: UserEntity;
}
```

recipe.entity.ts

```
@Entity({ name: 'recipes' })
export class RecipeEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  slug: string;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  description: string;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  body: string;

  // more fields
  
  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.recipes, { eager: true })
  author: UserEntity;
}
```

recipe.service.ts

```
async findAll(query: any) {
    const queryBuilder = getRepository(RecipeEntity)
      .createQueryBuilder('recipes')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('recipes.author', 'author');

    queryBuilder.orderBy('recipes.createdAt', 'DESC');
    
    if (query.author) {
      const author = await this.userRepository.findOne({
        username: query.author,
      });

      queryBuilder.andWhere('recipes.authorId = :id', {
        id: author.id,
      });
    }

    const recipes = await queryBuilder.getMany();

    return { recipes };
  }
```

I have already used `leftJoinAndSelect()` with the author, but in a `@OneToMany` relationship. How can I adjust my `findAll()` service function so that I can still see in my recipe-response the data from my `user` (author) table and also the associated data from the `ingredients`?

| ingredientsId | recipesId |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |

If I add following to the RecipeEntity:

```
  @ManyToMany(() => IngredientEntity, { eager: true })
  ingrec: IngredientEntity[];
```

I get an server error and `[Nest] 230  - 05/17/2022, 3:02:11 PM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Maximum call stack size exceeded`
Without `{ eager: true }` I don't get any errors but I also don't see any data from the ingredients table.